# set ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object > > value

Tags: android

I want to add the value like `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` to intent, and pass on `Activity` through broadc. The code like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
intent1.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listItem", listItem);
```

But it has the error:

> The method `putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)` in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments `(String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>)`

How to use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` specific? Through realizing Parcelable interface, can it return the `ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object > >` Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ArrayList implements Serializable, you don't have to do anything special to feed it to

Just Use `Intent.putExtra()` to put the values and use `getSerializableExtra()` to get the arraylist back to next activity.

Answer (score 3):

instead using `putParcelableAArrayListExtra`, use `putExtra` method. So change your code to following:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
intent1.putExtra("listItem", listItem);
```

and use `getSerializableExtra()`, to get the arraylist back to next activity.