# Android Parcelable - Write and read ArrayList< IA > when IA is a interface

Tags: java, android, interface, arraylist, parcelable

I have a interface **IA** and class **B** and **C** that implement them.
Both B and C implement `Parcelable` as well.

Then I have the tricky part:

Class **D** has a `ArrayList< IA >`. I need this too insert both classes B and C in the `arraylist`. They share the same structure but the **"IS-A"** relation don't apply.

I need to pass D from one activity to another as a Parcel.

I've tried to write `(ArrayList<IA>) in.readSerializable` but I got a **`IOException`**. I know that if IA was not a interface the problem was easy, but I can't seem to find an easy solution for this.

Any ideas?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public D (Parcel in) {
    list = new ArrayList<IA>();
    (...)    
    list = (ArrayList<IA>) in.readSerializable 
    }

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public D createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new D(in);
    }

    public D[] newArray(int size) {
        return new D[size];
    }
};

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    (...)
    dest.writeList(list);
}
```

Comment: IA should extend Parcelable

Comment: and D use in.readArrayList(list, Creator)? but which creator?

Comment: Could you post any code with class D's Parcelable method's to take a look.

Comment: I've edited the question with the solution (don't have enough reputation yet).

Comment: agreed with your solution, except this allows an implementation of IA that is not parcelable of serializable, hence crashing when you writeList.

Comment: hum I see where you are going. But extending parcelable on IA won't do the trick. Any suggestion?

Comment: Here's a prime example why you use `Cat`s and `Dog`s in examples. Jesus Christ, who's supposed to read this alphabet mess. To the poor soul who stumbles here: https://medium.com/@kcoppock/writing-parcelable-lists-with-inheritance-a739c42c055c#.th7o37yq3

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public D (Parcel in) {
    list = new ArrayList<IA>();
    (...)    
    //ERROR -> list = (ArrayList<IA>) in.readSerializable 
    list = in.readArrayList(IA.class.getClassLoader());
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public D createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new D(in);
    }

    public D[] newArray(int size) {
        return new D[size];
    }
};

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    (...)
    dest.writeList(list);
}
```

Comment: i have one problem i think you can help. I have ArrayList<HashMap<String, Boolean>> which i want to write to parcel and then read it in next activity. Can you please guide how to do that ?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228714/set-arraylist-hashmap-string-object-value

Comment: How to make sure that the "unchecked" warnings are not there? (Except suppressing them)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to install "Android Parcelable code generator" plugin. After this you can generate `writeToParcel` function, constructor which reads from parcel and creator class only whith clicking `Alt+Insert` buttons.